# Corda - New parameter is mandatory, should be nullable for evolution to work

Tags: corda

I've been running a CorDapp using Corda Enterprise 3.2 and a SQL Server database. Having recently updated the CorDapp, I'm now seeing this error:

> Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException:
>   net.corda.core.contracts.TransactionState ->
>   net.corda.core.contracts.TransactionState ->
>   data(net.corda.core.contracts.ContractState) ->
>   invoices(java.util.Set) -> java.util.Set<com.demo.Model> -> New
>   parameter foo is mandatory, should be nullable for evolution to work

Why did the upgrade cause this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

State evolution in Corda requires that all new fields added to the state are nullable, since they may be created from previous versions of the state which don't have the field, nullable is the only logical option for instantiating states against the new object structure.

For example...

```
data class OldState(val foo: Int)

data class NewState(val foo: Int, var bar: String? = null)
```

An upgrade from `OldState` to `NewState` would map `foo` to `foo` because the properties are identical, but would leave `bar` as null, because there was nothing in the previous state to populate that field with a non-nullable value.